# export to excel from ajax request asp.net MVC kendo UI

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, excel

I am working on a asp.net MVC with kendo UI.
I want a custom button to install the data from a specific date into Excel. 
I cannot use the ".Excel" in the grid because I need to filter the data before I install them.

I tried to connect to a method with ajax request:

```
 toolbar.Template(
            @<div>
                <label>@WebResources.LogFilterText</label>
                @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
                                                .Name("datepicker")
                                                .Value(DateTime.Today)
                                                .Format("dd.MM.yyyy")
                )
                @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                                        .Name("excelButton")
                                        .Events(e => e.Click("getExcel"))
                                        .Content("To Excel")
                )
            </div>
            )
```

this is the javscript function:

```
function getExcel() {
        var url = '/LogAdmin/GetExcel/';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { id: kendo.toString($("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker").value(), "dd.MM.yyyy") }, //parameters go here in object literal form
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert("da");
                $("#test").html(data);
            },
            error: function () { alert("Error has been accured."); }
        });

    }
```

and here is the controller method:

```
public ActionResult GetExcel([Bind(Prefix = "id")] string date)
        {

            // result is a valid list from Linq. 
            GridView gridview = new GridView();
            gridview.DataSource = result;
            gridview.DataBind();

            // Clear all the content from the current response
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            // set the header
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename = itfunda.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            Response.Charset = "";
            // create HtmlTextWriter object with StringWriter
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    // render the GridView to the HtmlTextWriter
                    gridview.RenderControl(htw);
                    // Output the GridView content saved into StringWriter
                    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

I do not get an error, and I receive an html table. if I show it on a div then it looks a like a correct table. 
but how to save it to excel? anybody can help me?

Comment: A few possible options: actually apply the filter the grid first then use built-in export, use server-side excel processing(http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/excel-export), use the excelExport event to filter the data just before it is written to excel(http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-excelExport), use the kendo ooxml api to create the xlsx from your returned dataset.  I'd probably go with server-side processing use the Telerik Document Processing library which should avoid most problems with large datasets.

Comment: Actually I go with your last advice "server side". I used EPPlus library and now everything is working. thank you